# WPF Datagridtextcolumn sorting not working on first click after setting sortmember path

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagridtextcolumn

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="HiddenColumn" Visibility="Hidden" Header="Make" CanUserResize="True" Binding="{Binding Make}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Car" MinWidth="50" Width="150" MaxWidth="150" CanUserResize="True" Binding="{Binding car}" SortMemberPath="Make" />
```

without using the sort member path , the column sorts.

But when i use `sortmemberpath`, for the first click on the column header there is no sort, from the second click it works fine.

Both columns display string.

Strange behaviour, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this link help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296532/making-a-datagrid-column-header-sortable-in-wpf-using-c-sharp

Comment: Nope, sorting does not work only for the first time click.

Comment: I have tried the code, and it works for me... Could something else be interfering? Handling the click first? Have you tried adding some code to the `Sorting` event of the control, to see if it fires?

Comment: @SimonEvans The other columns work perfectly for me, i tried sorting event its firing up.

Comment: @SainathNaik what is your collection source? Is this post relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985125/wpf-datagrid-default-sort-not-working

Comment: @SimonEvans: i am using the obsevable collection as shown in the post, if i remove sortmemberpath, then it sorts . But i need to sort column 2 based on column 1.